# How do I find documents containing digits and dollar signs in Solr?

Tags: solr

In Solr, I've got text that contains $30 and 30.

I would like to search for $30 and only find documents containing $30.

But if someone searches for 30, they should find both documents containing $30 and those containing 30.

Here is the field type I'm currently using to index my text field:

```
<!-- Just like text_en_splitting, but with the addition of reversed tokens for leading wildcard matches -->
<fieldType name="text_en_splitting_reversed" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
      add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
      analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
    -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" types="word-delim-types.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true"
       maxPosAsterisk="3" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
 </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"  types="word-delim-types.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I have defined word-delim-types.txt to contain:

```
$ => DIGIT
% => DIGIT
. => DIGIT
```

So when I search for $30, it correctly locates documents containing "$30" but not those containing just "30". That's good. But when I search for "30" it does not find documents containing "$30", only those containing "30".

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to my question. Instead of defining $ % and . as DIGIT, I now define them as ALPHA, in my "types" file that is passed in as an attribute to the WordDelimiterFilterFactory.

```
$ => ALPHA
% => ALPHA
. => ALPHA
```

Due to the rest of my WordDelimiterFilterFactory settings, things are broken up and catenated in a way where the desired effect is achieved:

Searching for $30 yields only documents containing $30.
Searching for 30 yields documents containing both $30 and 30.

Comment: Where did you find that option? In the Filter documentation it isn't specified (but anhow, it works!)?