# Using StandardTokenizerFactory with currency

Tags: solr, lucene

The fieldType config descrived in this question works for me to detect currency (eg. docs containing "$30" ). However, we wish to use the StandardTokenizerFactory, rather than the WhiteSpaceTokenizerFactory - and this config returns false positives with the StandardTokenizerFactory (eg. docs containing the digits 30 without the $ symbol). What is the solution?

Thanks

[How do I find documents containing digits and dollar signs in Solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886310/how-do-i-find-documents-containing-digits-and-dollar-signs-in-solr)

Comment: If it's working with `WhiteSpaceTokenizer` why would you want to change to one that doesn't work the way you want?

Comment: My initial guess would be that StandardTokenizer splits on $ as well, so test that assumption first - if it does, you wouldn't get $10 as a single token to process, and might have to extend it by generating shingles before processing them in the same way as in the question linked. Use the analysis page to see what's happening with your example text.

Comment: Looks like the StandardTokenizer discards the $ currency symbol. I tried adding in a ShingleFilterFactory but that didn't help either. I also tried the ClassicTokenizer, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved via a post to the solr user group 
http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/How-to-use-the-StandardTokenizer-with-currency-td4308072.html#a4308097

Here is my config

```
<!-- VB - Just like text_general, but supports $ currency matching and autoGeneratePhraseQueries -->
<fieldType name="text_curr_3" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping.txt"/>
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\$" replacement="xxdollarxx"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="xxdollarxx" replacement="\$" replace="all"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" types="word-delim-types.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping.txt"/>
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\$" replacement="xxdollarxx"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="xxdollarxx" replacement="\$" replace="all"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"  types="word-delim-types.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>   
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```